# How to change card_view:cardCornerRadius programmatically

Tags: android, android-cardview, cornerradius, cardview

In my project, I am using `RecyclerView` in my listing using `CardView`. In my listing I have to set the corner radius  of `CardView` dynamically based on device.

Is there any way to set cardview corner radius value dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you got any solution ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use `CardView.setRadius(float)`, see [androidx.cardview](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView?hl=en#setRadius(float)).

(It is worth noting that this will have no effect if you also invoke `setBackgroundColor`, make sure to use `setCardBackgroundColor` instead).

You must specify a pixel size, rather than dp value, e.g. for corner radius of 4dp you can invoke, in Kotlin:

```
radius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4f, context.resources.displayMetrics)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working, get backs to default atrubites

Comment: @Sam You need to use a dp to px conversion

Comment: It results in white background around the corners.

Comment: I have programmatically generated CardViews and tried adding them in a LinearLayout inside Horizontal ScrollView. but this code doesnot work even when documentation says it should. I know it's been marked correct, but is there anything that I need to look for ?

Comment: Yes same issue as @SoumyadeepGhosh this is not useful for me. Any other solution ?

Comment: @BhavenShah Have you applied any "background color" to the CardView, rather than "Card Background Colour" ?

Comment: yes, I applied both the same color. My issue solved by removing background color. Thanks.

Comment: Wondering why `setBackgroundColor` makes the radius redundant. Would have taken me forever to fix it had I not read the note that you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Your clarification with setCardBackgroundColor saves lives